# Cant get helper test to run - Rails/Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to test a helper in a Rails application.  I am new at `rspec` and am having a hard time getting the test to run.  Here is my test file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "ServiceHoursHelpers" do
  include ServiceHoursHelper

  describe "test" do
    it "should equal Jason" do
      test.should eql("Test")
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my test file:

```
module ServiceHoursHelper
  def test
    "Test"
  end
end
```

Here is the command I am running
`rspec spec/helpers/service_hours_helper_spec.rb`

It isnt succeeding and there are no errors, so obviously I am not hitting the code. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Could you not use the sensitive method name like `test`?

Comment: I can use any name.  I am just trying to get the code to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try run your test method like this:

```
helper.test.should eql("Test")
```

Comment: The code still isn't running.  I am not even hitting the code currently.  I am only getting `0 examples, 0 failures' just like before.

Comment: I had a duplicate file in another folder that I was running.  All is well now with the code above.